# Built-in sorted() function in Python

Tags: python, function, sorting, arguments

I saw in a book how to pass a specific sorting function to Python's own built-in sorted() function as follows:

```py
def mysort(a, b):
    if a[3] < b[3]:
        return -1
    elif a[3] > b[3]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

data = [
('Alpha Centauri A', 4.3, 0.26, 1.56),
('Alpha Centauri B', 4.3, 0.077, 0.45),
('Alpha Centauri C', 4.2, 0.00001, 0.00006),
("Barnard's Star", 6.0, 0.00004, 0.0005),
('Wolf 359', 7.7, 0.000001, 0.00002),
('BD +36 degrees 2147', 8.2, 0.0003, 0.006),
('Luyten 726-8 A', 8.4, 0.000003, 0.00006),
('Luyten 726-8 B', 8.4, 0.000002, 0.00004),
('Sirius A', 8.6, 1.00, 23.6),
('Sirius B', 8.6, 0.001, 0.003),
('Ross 154', 9.4, 0.00002, 0.0005),
]

sorted_data = sorted(data, mysort)
```

the code above sorts the data based on the 4th element of the 4-element tuple. Here, I am trying to figure out how the sorted() function feeds the `a` and `b` arguments to the `mysort` function. My intention is passing another argument to the `mysort` function similar to:

```
def mysort(a, b, i):
    if a[i] < b[i]:
        return -1
    elif a[i] > b[i]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

where it will tell the function which element should the sorting be based on. I am confused, because in the line

```
sorted_data = sorted(data, mysort)
```

we do not pass any arguments to the `mysort` function. The `sorted()` function seems to do its own magic, and provide the `a` and `b` arguments to the `mysort` function. To summarize, I wonder if there is a way to add a 3rd argument to the `mysort` function for different sorting types?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really want to use the `key` argument instead; sorting on the 4th column with [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

sorted(data, key=itemgetter(3))
```

or you could use a `lambda`:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda elem: elem[3])
```

or you could use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def mykeyfunc(column, item):
    return item[column]

sorted(data, key=partial(mykeyfunc, 3))
```

All 3 options create a *new* callable that is passed each item in `data`.

The `cmp` argument to `sorted()` has been removed in Python 3.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is there an advantage of using `itemgetter` over using a `lambda` as the `key` argument?

Comment: `itemgetter`, being implemented in C, would be faster.

Answer (score 3):

You usually don't sort with `cmp` (the second argument). The `key` argument is the best choice 99% of the time:

```
def mysort(item):
    return item[3]

sorted_data = sorted(data, key=mysort)
```

Or more concisely:

```
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda item: item[3])
```

To make your second function work, you need to create a function with your function:

```
def mysort(i):
    def sort_func(a, b)
        if a[i] < b[i]:
            return -1
        elif a[i] > b[i]:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    return sort_func
```

And use it like:

```
sorted(data, mysort(3))
```

But a better way would be to use something builtin:

```
from operator imoprt itemgetter

sorted_data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(3))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply! It seems there is a consensus on using `itemgetter`. Now I wonder why would it be better than using a `lambda`...